# AWS CLI retrieve the ARN of the newly created policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I want to create an IAM policy and attach it to some IAM role using AWS command-line interface.

Creating policy is quite simple:

```
aws iam create-policy --policy-name "${policy_name}" --policy-document file://policy.json
```

But to attach the newly created policy to the target role I must know the ARN of the policy:

```
aws iam attach-role-policy --role-name "${role_name}" --policy-arn "${policy_arn}"
```

What is the correct way to retrieve ARN of the newly created policy?

Right now I'm construcing `policy_arn` myself using `policy_name` and the `account_id`:

```
policy_arn=arn:aws:iam::"${account_id}":policy/"${policy_name}"
```

This is how I retrieve the `account_id`:

```
account_id=$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query 'SecurityGroups[0].OwnerId' --output text)
```

However this feels quite hacky.

Is there a better way to find out ARN of the created policy?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you add `--output text` to your `create-policy`, it will print the ARN.

```
aws iam create-policy --policy-name "${policy_name}" --policy-document file://policy.json --output text
```

You can get the policies and their ARN:

```
aws iam list-policies --query 'Policies[*].[PolicyName, Arn]' --output text
```

To get the ARN for just one policy:

```
aws iam list-policies --query 'Policies[?PolicyName==`FullAccess`].Arn' --output text
```

Output:

```
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/FullAccess
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this

```bash
POLICY_ARN=$(aws iam create-policy --policy-name xxx --policy-document file://xxx.json --output text --query Policy.Arn)
```